# How to disable link color change in html created in python

Tags: python, html

I am creating html page using python. The page gets created with links, but when I click on the link, it permanently changes the color of the link. I know in HTML we can disable it, but somehow it is not working when created in python.

Following is my code:

```
htmlFile = open('web.html','w')
htmlFile.write("<html>\n")
htmlFile.write("<head>\n")
htmlFile.write("<title> Web page </title>\n")
htmlFile.write("</head>\n")
htmlFile.write("<body>\n")
htmlFile.write(' <a href = "abcd.html"> abcd > <\a><br>\n')
htmlFile.write("</body>\n")
htmlFile.write("</html>\n")
htmlFile.close()
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: @Rachel : Yes I tried hard that way. but somehow its not working. I know it is a very small change, but unable to do it in python.

Comment: glad you found an answer! i think i learnt something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
htmlFile = open('web.html','w')
htmlFile.write("<html>\n")
htmlFile.write("<head>\n")
htmlFile.write("<style>a:visited {color:#00ffff;text-decoration:none;}</style>\n")
# add the above line in
htmlFile.write("<title> Web page </title>\n")
htmlFile.write("</head>\n")
htmlFile.write("<body>\n")
htmlFile.write(' <a href = "abcd.html"> abcd > <\a><br>\n')
htmlFile.write("</body>\n")
htmlFile.write("</html>\n")
htmlFile.close()
```

The method for doing what you want to is the same. It is just written to the file using python. Did this solution work for you?